# Referencing multiple cells in getpivotdata

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am creating a table based on the calculation of two set of values from a pivot table using the getpivotdata formula.

I need to reference two cells in order to define the operation.

Without the referencing the formula works like this

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Count of Client name]",
'Lessons per level'!$A$6,
"[Range].[Date]",
"[Range].[Date].&[**31-03-2016**]",
"[Range].[CO Time]",
"[Range].[CO Time].&[**5:00:00 AM**]",
"[Range].[Level]",
"[Range].[Level].&[Group Level: A1]"
)/GETPIVOTDATA(
"[Measures].[Distinct Count of Service provider]",
'Lessons per level'!$A$6,
"[Range].[Date]",
"[Range].[Date].&[**31-03-2016**]",
"[Range].[CO Time]",
"[Range].[CO Time].&[**5:00:00 AM**]",
"[Range].[Level]",
"[Range].[Level].&[Group Level: A1]"
)
```

Since I will be changing the dates on the table I'd like the formula to refer cell C2 instead of having to directly write the date **31-03-2016** into the formula. Similarly I'd like the time (**5:00:00 AM**) to refer to cell B5

Hope this is clear